# JQuery Datatables scrollbar and column search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using [JQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and trying to add a scrollbar to fit in the screen as well as column search in the header. It is **breaking the header** (if I click on the ordering, then my custom headers are gone) and the **search doesn't work** (happens only when the scrollbar is there).

My code (don't change the html as I am adding all data dynamically):

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
});

$('#example thead th').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
});

table.columns().every(function() {
  var that = this;

  $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
      that
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmxynxL8/25/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `DataTable()` after having added the elements for column filtering, otherwise DataTables plugin will modify your HTML on search, ordering, updating...

So you could add input field to a new row, prepended to column headers:

```js
// Create search header
var new_row = $("<tr class='search-header'/>");
$('#example thead th').each(function(i) {
  var title = $(this).text();
  var new_th = $('<th style="' + $(this).attr('style') + '" />');
  $(new_th).append('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" data-index="'+i+'"/>');
  $(new_row).append(new_th);
});
$('#example thead').prepend(new_row);

// Init DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  "searching": true
});

// Filter event handler
$( table.table().container() ).on( 'keyup', 'thead input', function () {
  table
    .column( $(this).data('index') )
    .search( this.value )
    .draw();
});
```

```css
.search-header {
    background: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is also your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/1pede2q3/

---

If you could change your HTML footer here is a solution proposed on DataTables docs showing column searching text inputs at the bottom: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: This resets the custom `thead` elements I create on table init

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because jquery datatables has no knowledge of the `<input/>` fields you are adding, so they are removed any time the table structure needs to change. You need to place those outside the table structure or find another way to implement that feature.